# Manage network bandwidth on Android

Tags: android, voip, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling

Is there an API to dynamically control how much bandwidth each application is taking in Android?

For example if I want to start using a VOIP application and I want to make sure it gets all/most of the bandwidth available ?

Comment: Take a look as well at the articles here about how to use the network most efficiently. It also explains that connecting to the network on a phone is quite different than on a computer. The setup/pull down of the network is quite key to understanding how to implement your network code. https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042